# jQuery Change Value Using Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple elements that'll have the same data attributes but with different values, how can I get jQuery to change the value?

Below is some example HTML.

```
<div data-one="test" data-two="test2"></div>
<div data-one="testing" data-two="hello"></div>
<div data-one="yo" data-two="test3"></div>
```

By default, I would like to the value of `div` to be `data-one` but then when the class `active` is on the `body` tag, I would like it to change all the values to the `data-two` value.

I thought about storing values as a variable which would be easier although the divs don't have any ID's and they're scattered around in the DOM which makes it difficult.

So far I had this:

```
if($('body').hasClass('active')) {
  $('div').html($(div).data('two'));
}
```

Comment: `<div>`s don't have values. `.val()` is for form elements.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `html` method.

```
var has = $('body').hasClass('active');
$('div').html(function() {
    return has ? $(this).data('two') : $(this).data('one');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44Du5/

Answer (score 0):

CSS only solution:

```
body div:after {
    content: attr(data-one);
}
body.active div:after {
    content: attr(data-two);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/gaeUR/

However it's not crossbrowser: [attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function is supporter in IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/rjR6q/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('body').hasClass('active')) {
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).data('two'));
});
}
 else
{
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).data('one'));
});
}
});
```